# Goal Seek Macro Giving Nonsensical Answers

Tags: excel, vba

I have been looking at this code for way too long and cannot figure out the issue, so any insight would be appreciated!

I am trying to create a goal seek in VBA that will look at the baseline production of people at a given year and change a value to hit a target production of people in that same year.

The code works perfectly until we get to the goalseek piece in the Macro and TargetFound keeps coming up as false.

```
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("C13:" & Cells(13, Cells(13, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Address)
            If Trim(cell.Value) <> "" Then
     cadreName = Left(Trim(cell.Value), InStrRev(cell.Value, " ") - 1)
     cadreColRef = Split(cell.Address, "$")(1)
    
    If (Trim(ActiveSheet.Range(cadreColRef + "21")) <> "") Then
                    targetMethod = LCase(Trim(ActiveSheet.Range(cadreColRef + "21")))
    
     Select Case targetMethod
                        Case "manual entry"
                            targetValRow = "25"
                        Case Else
                            targetValRow = "23"
                    End Select

If (Trim(ActiveSheet.Range(cadreColRef + targetValRow)) <> "" And IsNumeric(Trim(ActiveSheet.Range(cadreColRef + targetValRow)))) Then
                    originalScaleUp = ActiveSheet.Range(cadreColRef + "41").Value 

TargetFound = Sheets("Assumptions Tab").Range(cadreColRef + "27").GoalSeek(Goal:=Sheets("Assumptions Tab").Range(cadreColRef + targetValRow).Value, ChangingCell:=Sheets("Assumptions Tab").Range(cadreColRef + "41"))
```

Let me know if anyone can help! If additional code is necessary, please let me know!

Comment: `GoalSeek` returns a boolean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSvJH.png. The result of `False` means that the goal seek was unsuccessful. If your problem is that you expected `True`, well more context is necessary to help further.

Comment: `cadreColRef + "27"`: I would rather write `cadreColRef & "27"` to be safe. & is the concatenation operator.

Comment: @BigBen I was expecting it to return True. Somewhere after duplicating this file and making multiple versions this macro broke. Let me copy and paste some more code in the prompt!

Comment: I don't think we need more code, but more context around the goal seek.

Comment: @BigBen I updated just in case, but ultimately I am take a baseline production of people (which I get by index/match from a different sheet), and then try to iterate a factor change to get to a target number (which I get by index/match from another sheet) of production of people for that same year